# Finding $f(2020)$ given that $f(n+m) + f(n-m) = f(3n)$

Tags: functional-equations

Assume we have a function $f$ such that $\mathbb Z^{0+} \rightarrow R,$ and $f(n+m) + f(n-m) = f(3n).$ If $n,m \in \mathbb Z^{0+},$ find $f(2020).$

---

My immediate thought process for this was to substitute small values of $n$ and $m$ in order to try and find $f(2020),$ but I realized that $\frac{2020}{3}$ wasn't an integer and therefore I couldn't just substitute in $n = \frac{2020}{3}.$ Are there any other ways to begin on this problem?

Comment: **Hint.** What is $f(0)$?  Then compare $m = 1$ with $m = 0$, for any $n$.  What can you conclude?

Comment: Well, if we let $n = 0,$ than $f(0)$ should be equal to $f(m) + f(-m).$

Comment: $f$ isn't defined for negative arguments, so in order to make sense of your last statement, $m$ must be...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $n \ge 1$, we have
$$
   f(n+1) + f(n-1) = f(3n) = f(n) + f(n)
$$
and therefore $f(n+1) = 2f(n) - f(n-1)$. This is a two-term linear recurrence to which all solutions have the form $f(n) = an + b$. Substituting this into the functional equation gives us
$$
     2an + 2b = 3an + b   \implies an = b
$$
which can only hold for all $n$ if $a=b=0$. Therefore $f(2020)=0$ as well.